# How do I assign a value using = when a setter is passed?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, defineproperty

I am write a compatibility layer over a legacy library function whose internal signature looks like —

```
function legacyLibraryFunction(context) {
  context.foo.bar = "data"
  return context
}
```

The new system however, doesn't recommend assigning custom properties directly to `context` and instead recommends using the `context.set()` method.

How do I pass `context` from the new system to the old one so that `context.foo="data"` ends up called `context.set('foo', data)` instead?

I'm guessing I can use Object.defineProperty for this, but I don't really understand how.

Comment: what version of javascript are you working with?

Comment: is this for a setter in particular or any setter that might be used on the context object? The latter requires proxies.

Comment: @Paarth This particular one. I need to handle only one property in the legacy function's signature

Answer (score 0):

#### Using a setter:

You can use a setter for this:

```
var wrappedContext = {
    set foo(val) {
        context.set('foo',val);
    }
}
```

Note: I'm assuming `context.foo` instead of `context.foo.bar` because the second part of your question does not quite match the example code.

This will create an object (`wrappedContext`) that will have a `foo` property that will call `context.set()` when you assign a value to it. So then you can do:

```
legacyLibraryFunction(wrappedContext);
```

#### Using a proxy:

Since you're using node 6.6 you can also use a proxy:

```
var wrappedContext = new Proxy(context,{
  set: function(obj, prop, value) {
    obj.set(prop,value);
  }
});
```